# Instantiate distorts the prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There is an enemy that launches fireballs from the FireballBox object, which is attached to it, the launch of fireballs is implemented through calling prefabs. And everything seems to work fine, the balls fly as they should, but if the enemy turns 90 degrees to the left or right (watching the player all this time), then the fireballs are deformed, stupidly stretched in breadth. The Fireball script is attached to the fireball itself, and FireballRotation is attached to the FireballBox and is responsible for the fireball's flight path. On the first screen there is a normal fireball, on the second it is already in the other direction and distorted. Help, please, who can come across such that the size of the prefab is always normal.[image]
[image]

```
public class Fireball : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int Speed;
    Vector3 lastPos;
    private GameObject FBPrefab;
    public GameObject arr;
    [SerializeField] private float hitCooldown = 1.5f;
    public float cooldown = 0;
    public float attackSpeed = 1f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        FBPrefab = Resources.Load("Fireball1") as GameObject;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (cooldown > -0.5)
        {
            cooldown -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if (cooldown <= 0)
        {
            //FBPrefab.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1.5, 2.5, 4.5);
            GameObject newArrow = Instantiate(FBPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            //newArrow.transform.position = transform.position;
            //newArrow.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, -180, -180));
            Rigidbody rb = newArrow.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            rb.velocity = transform.forward * Speed;
            Destroy(newArrow, 2);
            cooldown = hitCooldown * attackSpeed;
        }
    }

    public void Shoot()
    {
        if (cooldown <= 0)
        {
            //FBPrefab.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(90, 0, 90));
            GameObject newArrow = Instantiate(FBPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            //newArrow.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, -180, -180));
            //newArrow.transform.position = transform.position;
            Rigidbody rb = newArrow.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            rb.velocity = transform.forward * Speed;
            Destroy(newArrow, 2);
            cooldown = hitCooldown * attackSpeed;
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class FireballRotation : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody rb;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(-90.0f, -90.0f, 0.0f));
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(rb.velocity);
    }
}
```

I could not find any information on this, I tried everything, but it does not work out to fix it. Although even the scale of the called prefab does not change.

Comment: I assume you're using a particle system for the fireball? If so change the render mode,  render alignment etc in the renderer module of the system: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PartSysRendererModule.html

Comment: I tried all the options in RA, but none of them worked. Unless, with Facing, the ball was not distorted, but at the same time the ball itself does not fly in the correct position. I'll try to work with this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unity Novice here so, this may not be helpful - but it is quick. Is it an inheritance problem?  Are the fireballs implicitly instantiated as children of the FireballBox object, or given transform or rotation from it?  If the update function keeps assigning values to the fireball from the FireballBox object, it would change if the enemy's rotation changed since the FireballBox is a child of the enemy.

FireballRotation is attached to the FireBallBox. If the FireBallBox is a child of the Enemy, it will inherit the features of the Enemy.  If you do not specify otherwise, the location and rotation of the FireBallBox are based upon the Enemy object and not the world around it.  When the enemy rotates, it changes the starting position AND rotation for any projectiles shot out out of the box.  Depending upon the way your script is written, you may have your fireball being launched in a different way, which could affect the way it appears on the screen.

Let's say your enemy is a pitcher throwing a ball with a streamer attached.  When your enemy turns, imagine what happens when he throws the ball.  What would it look like from above?

Anyhow, I said I was a novice, but this all I can think of.  Also take a look at your prefab and your script and see how the prefab's rotation is defined. ===> or take a look at the other answer - your scaling factor may make it look smushed.  Good luck.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. I have a separate special folder resources, it contains the prefab of my fireball. In the specified script, I do not change the rotation or scale of the prefab, they fly as they are indicated. Update does not give any values for fireballs.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

From what you are describing, I understand you instantiate the fireball under an object with a scale that is not the same on all axis.
Let me explain: If the parent object's scale is for example (1, 0.5, 1), then objects spawned as its children will spawn normally if the y-axis is pointing at the world y-axis. But, when you rotate the object, for example, 90 degrees on the x-axis, the scale of the parent will "squish" the child object in half on the parent's y-axis.